# AWS CloudFormation ImportValue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a question regarding Fn::ImportValue function in CloudFormation. For example, one SNS Topic from Stack 1 is imported in Stack 2. What happens, if I try to change name of this topic in Stack 1? Will it trigger redeployment of Stack 2? If not, will the changes be recognized anyhow by resources created by Stack 2? Thank you.

Kind regard

Oleksii

Answer (score 3):

Your update probably will fail, as you can't modify exported values if they are imported by other stacks. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-stack-exports.html):

> After another stack imports an output value, you **can't** delete the stack that is exporting the output value or **modify the exported output value**. All of the imports must be removed before you can delete the exporting stack or modify the output value.